# Regarding joining of threads

Tags: java

I have developed the below program on java threads , I have two threads which are executing and accessing the method inside run() now if I want to first thread to begin first and then second thread that I have done through synchronization mechanism but if I want first thread to end first and then began with second thread that could be achievable through join() , please advise me how this can be done by implementing join,

```
public class MyThread2 extends Thread  {


public  void  run()
{

    //synchronized (this)
    //{
    //System.out.println(Thread.class);
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        try{

            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println(i +"\n"+ "..");
        }catch(Exception e)
        {e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //}
```

}

```
public static void main(String... a )
{
    MyThread2 obj = new MyThread2();

    Thread x = new Thread(obj);
    x.setName("first");
    x.start();

    Thread y = new Thread(obj);
    y.setName("second");
    y.start();




}
```

Comment: If you want the first thread to end before you start the second thread why are you using threads at all? It's just a complicated way of calling two methods one after the other.

Answer (score 1):

```
x.start();
x.join();
y.start();
```

but you should realize that this is completely pointless as per my comment above. If you want sequential execution all you need is:

```
x.run();
y.run();
```

and you don't need either of them to extend `Thread`.

Comment: Hi EJP, Thanks a lot, it works , Now My first thread starts and then after it completion the second threads starts , please once again explain a little bit that what is happening by x.start();
x.join();
y.start();
what I grasp is that first x thread begins and after it completion the y threads begin, please expalin a little bit

Comment: `start()` starts the thread. `join()` joins it to the current thread, as per the Javadoc: the current thread waits until the target thread is finished.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to extend threads in case you want the jobs to run sequenially. But if you want to control the order the threads get executed then you could try to set priorities to the threads.

```
//Setting priorities on the Thread objects
    x.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    y.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
```

If we set the priority on the threads we still haven't got exact control of the execution, but at least we can tell the CPU which one we think is
most important

Hope this has helped you.

Comment: Hi , that is not guaranteed what it is doing it is running first and then immediately run second and cycle goes like that, what i was looking for first one thread would completes it's task and then second thread should begin as a fresh..!! anyways thanks for the help..!